# how to change image size using actual image in if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Script Code is not Running i need image top and bottom spaces above width 1000px images and below width 1000px images then take width and height in else if condition

Please can solve my script problem

```js
var yourImg = document.getElementById('yourImgId');
if(yourImg && yourImg.style > 1000) { /*  image actual size above 1000px then set below height and width */
    yourImg.style.height = '200px';
    yourImg.style.top = '20px';
    yourImg.style.bottom = '20px';
    yourImg.style.width = '200px';
}
else if (yourImg && yourImg.style < 1000) /*  image actual size below  1000px then set below height and width */
{
  yourImg.style.height = '200px';
    yourImg.style.width = '200px';

}
```

```html
<div style="  border-right:1px solid #fff; "> 
 <a href="#">
 <img  class="img-responsive" alt="product" src="http://olpur.com/admin2/products/15201small.jpg" id="yourImgId" style=" width:100%;border:none;  object-fit: contain; object-position: top 75%;" />
                                            </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `yourImg.style`, I think you're trying to get the current width of the image using `yourImg.clientWidth`.

```
var yourImg = document.getElementById('yourImgId');

if (yourImg && yourImg.clientWidth > 1000) {
  yourImg.style.height = '200px';
  yourImg.style.top = '20px';
  yourImg.style.bottom = '20px';
  yourImg.style.width = '200px';
}
else if (yourImg && yourImg.clientWidth < 1000) {
  yourImg.style.height = '200px';
  yourImg.style.width = '200px'; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a35u2fm9/